# Error trigger. Trigger without return. PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I created trigger and function.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_quantity AFTER INSERT ON orderitem
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_quantity();

        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_quantity() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $quantity_update$
          DECLARE
            flower INT;
          BEGIN
            flower = New.flower_num;
            UPDATE product SET quantity = quantity - New.quantity
            WHERE flower_num = flower;
          END;
          $quantity_update$
        LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I try to insert a row into a table. Everything i have the following error.

```
INSERT INTO "public"."orderitem" ("order_num", "flower_num", "quantity", "total_price") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);

            [2F005] ERROR: control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN
            Where: PL/pgSQL function update_quantity()
```

Comment: I might be mistaken but I think a trigger function should return values he mlust use for his action (here INSERT). So in your example, I would return the NEW value.

Comment: I cannot return NEW. 
Give an example of what to return

Comment: You will find an example in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would write (not tested):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_quantity() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $quantity_update$
      DECLARE
        flower INT;
      BEGIN
        flower = New.flower_num;
        UPDATE product SET quantity = quantity - New.quantity
        WHERE flower_num = flower;
        RETURN NEW;
      END;
      $quantity_update$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_quantity AFTER INSERT ON orderitem
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_quantity();
```

Answer (score 1):

how is AFTER TRIGGER, you can return  RETURN OLD; or  RETURN NULL;